# Generating indices using np.triu_indices

Tags: python, numpy, indices

I would like call a function on each entry of an upper-triangular matrix. In order to avoid a messy nest of for loops, I am using the numpy.triu_indices function. My function works but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to implement the indexing.

```
import numpy as np
def weighted_edges(adjmat):
    indices = np.triu_indices(len(adjmat))
    return ((x, y, adjmat[x,y]) for (x,y) in zip(indices[0], indices[1]))
```

I suspect that there is a way to implement this without needing to reference indices[i] in the zip call. Is there indeed a way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an `N x N` matrix from which you want the upper triangular values, just do

```
import numpy as np
N = 5
x = np.arange(N**2).reshape(N, N)
upper = x[np.triu_indices(N, 0)]
```

If you want the triangular values offset from the main diagonal by `k` columns, then do

```
upper = x[np.triu_indices(N, k)]
```

Comment: The only thing left to get the same as the OP function returns, is to stack the three arrays together and transpose them: `np.vstack(indices+(adjmat[indices],)).T`

Comment: Thanks very much. @Jaime: That is exactly what I needed to finish. I am struggling to understand the + operation. `indices + adjmat[indices]` gives me a result I understand, but I do not understand why `indices + (adjmat[indices],)` performs a union, instead of vector addition (adding nothing to the second array in indices).

Comment: @EricKightley What `np.triu_indices` returns is a 2 element tuple, holding two arrays, one for indexing the rows, another for the columns. `np.vstack` needs a tuple (or list) of arrays to stack, so by adding the single element tuple `(adjmat[indices,)` to the `indices` tuple, we concatenate them and create a three element tuple, that gets stacked, and then transposed to fit your original output.